# Manipulate histogram in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, histogram

I have a large DataFrame in `pandas`. I want to remove **certain range of values** (not a single value) with have a lower frequency while plotting histogram.

For the image below, let's say I want to remove all the values of the variable of the Dataframe which correspond to count/frequency below 20. Does anyone have any solution to that?

```
# PR has value between 0 to 1700 
data['PR'].hist(bins = 160) #image on the left
data_openforest['PR'].hist(bins = 160) #image on the right
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: You could use `np.histogram` or `pd.cut` to compute the histogram and filter the counts.

Comment: Do you happen to have an example, for that? I got as far as `ranges = [i for i in np.arange(0,1600,10)]` and 
`count = data_openforest.groupby(pd.cut(data_openforest['Count'], ranges)).count()`. But how do I now apply this to my original dataframe.

Comment: This might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45751390/pandas-how-to-use-pd-cut

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using pd.cut like this should work:

```
out = pd.cut(data_openforest['PR'], bins=160)
counts = out.value_counts(sort=False)
counts[counts > 20].plot.bar()
plt.show()
```

If you want to filter your DataFrame, you have to do this:

```
data_openforest['bin'] = pd.cut(data_openforest['PR'], bins=160)
bin_freq = data_openforest.groupby('bin').count()
data_openforest = data_openforest.merge(bin_freq, 
                                        on='bin', 
                                        how='left',
                                        suffixes=("_bin", 
                                                  "_bin_freq"))
```

And then you can easily filter your DataFrame. You will then have to do a bar plot, not a hist.

Comment: Yes, I kind of got the range with my code too. But I have to manually look and do the filtering. Can you tell any way of using the code you mentioned directly for filtering the Dataframe without intervention?

Comment: Edited. Not sure what you mean by "without intervention".

Comment: Yes. Thank you, it's exactly what you just did. I was unsure about how to do the last step.