# Counting the no.of elements in a column and grouping them

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Hope you guys are doing well . I have taken up a small project to do in python so I can learn how to code and do basic data analysis in python along the way . I need some help on counting the number of elements present in a column in a DF and grouping them .
Below is the Dataframe I am using

```
    dates               open    high    low     close    volume % change
372 2010-01-05 15:28:00 5279.2  5280.25 5279.1  5279.5  131450  
373 2010-01-05 15:29:00 5279.75 5279.95 5278.05 5279.0  181200  
374 2010-01-05 15:30:00 5277.3  5279.0  5275.0  5276.45 240000  
375 2010-01-06 09:16:00 5288.5  5289.5  5288.05 5288.45 32750   0.22837324337386275
376 2010-01-06 09:17:00 5288.15 5288.75 5285.05 5286.5  55004   
377 2010-01-06 09:18:00 5286.3  5289.0  5286.3  5288.2  37650
```

I would like to create another DF where the count of elements/entries in the `% change` column and group them as , `x<= 0.5` or `0.5<x<=1` or `1<x<=1.5` or `1.5<x<=2` or `2<x<=2.5` or `X<2.5`

Below would be the desired output

```
Group         no.of instances
x<= 0.5          1
0.5<x<=1         0
1<x<=1.5         0
1.5<x<=2         0
2<x<=2.5         0
X<2.5            0
```

Looking forward to a reply ,

Fudgster

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas how to use pd.cut()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45751390/pandas-how-to-use-pd-cut)

Comment: You're looking for the [`pd.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) function.

Comment: pd.cut doesnt count the number of elements in the column and group them . thats the issue . I am not sure how to combine count() and pd.cut together.

Answer (score 0):

You could get the number of elements in each category by using the bins option of the pandas.value_counts() method.This would return the series with number of records within the specified range.
Here is the code,

```
df["% change"].value_counts(bins=[0,0.5,1,1.5,2,2.5])
```

Comment: hey Mayesh , I tried using the above code . it gives me an error saying "TypeError: bins argument only works with numeric data."

Comment: You will have to first deal with missing values in the "%change" column before performing the operation, I tweaked in some random values while trying the solution.Sorry I forgot to mention it.

Comment: Those are not missing values, that's how the dataframe is. Would added NaN to the empty cells work?

Comment: It would simply ignore the nan values and list out the remaining frequencies.You can check it in the API documentation also, https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html