# user defined function for if loop in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

Can there be a faster and efficient way of restructuring the following code

```
def g(i):
  if(0>=i<1):
    return '0-1'
  if(1>=i<2):
    return '1-2'

df['Bin]=df['Hours'].map(g)
```

The bins are created based on 24hrs of the day...The final dataframe should look like

```
Hour  Bin
2     2-3
1     1-2
19    19-20
```

Comment: I think you can use `pd.cut` see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45751390/pandas-how-to-use-pd-cut) post

Comment: Assuming the hours are ranged from 0-23, Try the code, `df["Hour"] = df["Hour"].apply(lambda x : str(x)+"-"+str(x+1))`

Comment: @SaravanakumarV try and rid your self of the apply here `df['Hour'].astype(str) + '-' +df['Hours'].add(1).astype(str)` would be more efficient

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def g(i):
  if(0>=i<1):
    return '0-1'
  if(1>=i<2):
    return '1-2'

df['Bin]=df['Hours'].apply(lambda x:'0-1' if 0>=x< 1 else '1-2' if 1>=x<2 else 'None')
```