# How to create a new column with status based on value

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following pandas dataframe

```
Suburb       Percentile Rank
Hume          0.20464135
Clayton       0.409162146
Moorabin      0.654550934
St Kilda      0.80464135
Point Cook   1.505447257
```

I want to create a new column called Rank classifier based on the "Percentile Rank" column value.

Rules would look like this;

```
perc_rank <= 0.2 then 'Very Low', 
perc_rank > 0.2 and perc_rank <= 0.4 then 'Low', 
perc_rank > 0.4 and perc_rank <= 0.6 then 'Medium', 
perc_rank > 0.6 and perc_rank <= 0.8 then 'High', 
perc_rank > 0.8 and perc_rank <= 1.0 then 'Very High'
```

I was able to produce Classifier output in SQL. But unable to do the same using python with creating a new column.

Tried this;

```
def Rank Classifier

     if (perc_rank  <= 0.2):
               Rank Classifier = "Very Low"
            elif (perc_rank > 2) & (perc_rank <= 0.4):
                Rank Classifier = "Low"
            elif (perc_rank > 0.4) & (perc_rank  <= 0.6):
                Rank Classifier = "Medium"
            elif (perc_rank  > 0.6) & (perc_rank <= 0.8):
                Rank Classifier = "High"
            elif (perc_rank > 8) & (perc_rank <=1 ):
                Rank Classifier = "Very High"
                
        else:
            return Rank Classifier
```

Getting an error

> IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Would like to return classifier data in new column called "Rank Classifier"

The output would look like the following:

```
Suburb  Percentile Rank  Rank Classifier
Hume        0.20464135      Very Low
Clayton     0.409162146     Low
Moorabin    0.654550934    Medium
St Kilda    0.80464135     High
Point Cook  1.505447257    Very High
```

Comment: Look at `pd.cut` https://stackoverflow.com/a/45751429/6361531

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of applying a function look at using [pandas.cut](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html).

The code below will give you the result you indicated you expected but you might need to tweak things.

```py
bins = [0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1, np.inf]
labels = ['Very Low', 'Low', 'Medium', 'High', 'Very High']

df['Rank Classifier'] = pd.cut(df['Percentile Rank'], bins=bins, labels=labels)
```

Note, like I said the above will give you the desired output you indicated in the question.

However, I'm not sure that desired output is correct.

For example, shouldn't `Hume` be classified as `Low` rather than `Very Low`.

Also, how can `Point Cook` have a `Percentile Rank` of 1.505447257?

I think you need to check your criteria.

P.S. The bins list should really start at 0 and the last value should be 1.

```py
bins = [0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1]
```

Comment: applied your suggestion and I was able to create a new column with classifier output but not the desired output.

Comment: Got the output. thanks for your help. just needed to add this at the end "ordered=False"

Answer (score 1):

try using apply

```
def RankClassifier(perc_rank):
    if (perc_rank  <= 0.2):
        return "Very Low"
    elif (perc_rank > 2) & (perc_rank <= 0.4):
        return "Low"
    elif (perc_rank > 0.4) & (perc_rank  <= 0.6):
        return "Medium"
    elif (perc_rank  > 0.6) & (perc_rank <= 0.8):
        return "High"
    elif (perc_rank > 8) & (perc_rank <=1 ):
        return "Very High"       
    else:
        return RankClassifier
    
df['Rank Classifier']= df['Percentile Rank'].apply(Classifier)
```

Comment: Hell @ade-1, thanks for your reply. i did try above sample script. But still I am getting this error.

  File "<tokenize>", line 5
    elif (Percentile_Rank > 2) & (Percentile_Rank <= 0.4):

   ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

df['Rank Classifier']= df['Percentile_Rank Rank'].apply(per_df)  <- per_df is my original df which I need to bind df['Rank Classifier']

Comment: from your error seems you needed to indent the elif statement