# Python: cannot perform both aggregation and transformation operations simultaneously, custom functions for `.agg` giving errors

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose you have the following Pandas DataFrame, df, with 4 columns and 10 rows. Here is a MWE:

```
data = {'age': [39, 50, 38, 53, 28, 37, 49, 52, 31, 42], 
        'education-num': [13, 13,  9,  7, 13, 14,  5,  9, 14, 13], 
        'workclass': ['State-gov', 'Self-emp-not-inc', 'Private', 'Private', 'Private', 'Private', 'Private', 'Self-emp-not-inc', 'Private', 'Private'],
        'income': ['<=50K', '<=50K', '<=50K', '<=50K', '<=50K', '<=50K', '<=50K', '>50K', '>50K', '>50K']
       }
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
finished_partitions = []

feature_columns = ['age', 'education-num', 'workclass']
finished_partitions = [Int64Index([2, 3, 6, 7], dtype='int64'),
                       Int64Index([4, 5, 8], dtype='int64'),
                       Int64Index([0, 1, 9], dtype='int64')]
feature_columns = ['age', 'education-num', 'workclass']


def agg_categorical_column(series):
    return [','.join(set(series))]

def agg_numerical_column(series):
    return [series.mean()]

## my code:

def Convert(a):
    it = iter(a)
    res_dct = dict(zip(it, it))
    return res_dct

aggregations = {}
for column in feature_columns:
        if column in categorical:
            aggregations[column] = agg_categorical_column # class 'function'. ex. output: {'age': <function agg_numerical_column at 0x7f314231c9e0>, 'education-num': <function agg_numerical_column at 0x7f314231c9e0>, 'workclass': <function agg_categorical_column at 0x7f314231c830>}
        else:
            aggregations[column] = agg_numerical_column   # class 'function'. ex. output: {'age': <function agg_numerical_column at 0x7f314231c9e0>, 'education-num': <function agg_numerical_column at 0x7f314231c9e0>, 'workclass': <function agg_categorical_column at 0x7f314231c830>}
            
partition = finished_partitions[0]
tmp = df.loc[partition] # Pandas DataFrame for partition, i, in partitions I
grouped_columns = tmp.agg(aggregations, squeeze=False) # Pandas Series
```

Which will generate the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.map_locations()

TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
Exception ignored in: 'pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine._call_map_locations'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 4588, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.map_locations
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-98-980ed492ad0c> in <module>
      1 partition = finished_partitions[0]
      2 tmp = df.loc[partition] # Pandas DataFrame for partition, i, in partitions I
----> 3 grouped_columns = tmp.agg(aggregations, squeeze=False) # Pandas Series

/emr/notebook-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in aggregate(self, func, axis, *args, **kwargs)
   7576         result = None
   7577         try:
-> 7578             result, how = self._aggregate(func, axis, *args, **kwargs)
   7579         except TypeError as err:
   7580             exc = TypeError(

/emr/notebook-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in _aggregate(self, arg, axis, *args, **kwargs)
   7607             result = result.T if result is not None else result
   7608             return result, how
-> 7609         return aggregate(self, arg, *args, **kwargs)
   7610 
   7611     agg = aggregate

/emr/notebook-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/aggregation.py in aggregate(obj, arg, *args, **kwargs)
    580     elif is_dict_like(arg):
    581         arg = cast(AggFuncTypeDict, arg)
--> 582         return agg_dict_like(obj, arg, _axis), True
    583     elif is_list_like(arg):
    584         # we require a list, but not an 'str'

/emr/notebook-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/aggregation.py in agg_dict_like(obj, arg, _axis)
    784         # There is a mix of NDFrames and scalars
    785         raise ValueError(
--> 786             "cannot perform both aggregation "
    787             "and transformation operations "
    788             "simultaneously"

ValueError: cannot perform both aggregation and transformation operations simultaneously
```

*Update*

@wwnde Not sure what the expected output is supposed to look like with this particular input data, as these are functions from a repo I'm trying to get to work. It's implementing an algorithm called k-anonymizer. Basically, supposed to condense the 10 rows into fewer than 10 rows that look something like

```
age:     education-num:   workclass                   income
28-31    7-14             ['State-gov', 'Private']    '<=50K'
42-52    13-14            ['Private']                 '>50K'
...
```

Note the following troubleshooting results:

```
df['age'].agg(agg_numerical_column) # works
[41.9]

aggregations['age']
<function __main__.agg_numerical_column(series)>

df['age'].agg(aggregations['age'])
[41.9]

df.agg(aggregations, squeeze=False) # gives error above
```

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: this isn't complete. can you define the aggregation functions? and my guess is this fails on every column, so no need to do the whole dictionary-of-functions thing, right? just try to create a dataframe and groupby.agg with one of those functions and see what breaks. My guess is you don't need to return e.g. [ser.mean()] but just ser.mean()

Comment: @MichaelDelgado you're right. added in the aggregate functions. Ok, I'll try to figure out how to try that.

Comment: Take a look into [`pd.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) (or directly on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45751390/pandas-how-to-use-pd-cut)).

Comment: what's the usage for `squeeze=False`? it seems be parsed as parameter in `aggregations`

Comment: your code doesn't run straight through, and if I fix the bugs by defining `categorical=['workclass', 'income']` it runs without error. Can you make sure your example does what you says it does?

Answer (score 2):

I think it's a bug related to [pandas/issues/41768](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/41768)

I minimize the demo code to:

```
data = {'workclass':
        ['State-gov', 'Self-emp-not-inc', 'Private']
       }
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

def agg_categorical_column(series):
    print(f'Input object type: {type(series)}')
    print(f'Input object looks like:\n {series}')
    return [','.join(set(series))]

aggregations = {}
aggregations['workclass'] = agg_categorical_column 

res = df[['workclass']].agg(aggregations['workclass']) # works
print('results is a series as expected.\n', res)

print('\n\n')
res = df[['workclass']].agg(aggregations) # not works, means agg acts like map each element
print('results is a dataframe but with strange value:\n', res)
```

Outputs:

```
Input object type: <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
Input object looks like:
 0           State-gov
1    Self-emp-not-inc
2             Private
Name: workclass, dtype: object
results is a series as expect.
                             workclass
0  Private,Self-emp-not-inc,State-gov



Input object type: <class 'str'>
Input object looks like:
 State-gov
Input object type: <class 'str'>
Input object looks like:
 Self-emp-not-inc
Input object type: <class 'str'>
Input object looks like:
 Private
results is a dataframe but with strange value:
                    workclass
0          [g,v,-,t,S,e,o,a]
1  [l,-,p,f,t,S,e,i,n,o,c,m]
2            [v,P,t,r,e,i,a]
```

Alternative:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

#income should be added, or removed if not used
categorical = ['workclass', 'income']

def agg_categorical_column(series):
    return [','.join(set(series))]
def agg_numerical_column(series):
    return [series.mean()]

# split it to 2 dataframe first
cat_df = df[[c for c in df.columns if c in categorical]]
num_df = df[[c for c in df.columns if c not in categorical]]

# then concat with separated num and cat method
pd.concat([num_df.agg(agg_numerical_column), cat_df.agg(agg_categorical_column)], axis=1)
```

Outputs:

```
    age education-num   workclass   income
0   41.9    11.0    Private,Self-emp-not-inc,State-gov  <=50K,>50K
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue and I found an easy workaround, sharing it in case it helps. Adding a dummy column with a single value and using `groupby` before aggregating produces the expected result without raising the error:

```py
#instead of
tmp = df.loc[partition] # Pandas DataFrame for partition, i, in partitions I
grouped_columns = tmp.agg(aggregations, squeeze=False) # Pandas Series

#use
tmp = df.loc[partition] # Pandas DataFrame for partition, i, in partitions I
tmp['dummy_id'] = 1
grouped_columns = tmp.groupby('dummy_id').agg(aggregations, squeeze=False).reset_index().drop('id', axis=1) # Pandas Series
```

The result is (using the same aggregation functions than in the example, returning lists):

```
    age     education-num       workclass                   income
0   [48]    [7.5]               [Self-emp-not-inc,Private]  [>50K,<=50K]
```

Comment: Damned missed this answer! this worked for me, thx!
My (rough) understanding / guess-what-is-going-on, now, is that the total aggregations gets thrown off track by the fact that a string is also a sequence of characters so it will try to aggregate along that dimension as well. by specifying the group-by it does not need to deduce what to aggregate, and it does as intended. cheers