# Making a pie chart for an array of floats of length 1000, with 5 categories

Tags: pandas, numpy, matplotlib, statistics

I am trying to plot a pie chart with regards to a selected column of floats. I have a column I want to work on and the pie chart is supposed to represent the ratio of each of the different values. The values in the column range between 0-10.0, and the categories are 0.0, 0.1-3.9, 4.0-6.9, 7.0-8.9, 9.0-10.0.

I have not tried anything yet as I am not sure how to to implement it yet.

I have made an arraylist containing all the values in the column, and I tried to make a pie chart based on the values in the array. The pie chart just looked like what is shown in the picture:

Comment: As you haven't tried anything, the minimum you should do is to provide a clean reproducible minimal dataset as input and a schematic of the expected graph

Comment: actually, I would need to group the data in different categories first. How would I do that?

Comment: Provide first an explicit example (data + schematic of graph)

Comment: See e.g. [Pandas how to use pd.cut()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45751390/pandas-how-to-use-pd-cut)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.