# How to create a new column with compartments based on values in another column in DataFrame in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, cut

I have Pandas Data Frame in Python like below (col1 is float data type):

```
col1
------
0.04
0.09
100.00
31.34
55.02
80.00
```

And I would like to create a new column (col2 with dtype string) grouping the values in the col1 column into ranges:

```
0-10
11-20
21-30
31-40
41-50
51-60
71-80
81-90
91-100
```

So as a resul I need someting like below:

```
col1   | col2
-------|------
0.04   | 0-10
0.09   | 0-10
100.00 | 91-100
31.34  | 31-40
55.02  | 51-60
80.00  | 71-80
```

How can I do that in Python Pandas ?

Comment: use pd.cut - https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.cut.html

Comment: could you show how to do that on my exaplme table ? I tried to do that but I do not know how

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45751390/pandas-how-to-use-pd-cut

Comment: srinath it is not ideally what I need because I need in col2 values as string for exaplme 41-50 not a tuple like in your example

Comment: .astype(str) will convert the column to string. you can remove parenthesis if needed. will that help?

Comment: could you write it as a code based on my exaplme data in question please ? srinath

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246852/discussion-between-srinath-and-ritendro).

Comment: I rather prefere to see answer here

Comment: Added an answer. check and lemme know if it helps

Answer (score 0):

bin using pd.cut

```
bins = [x * 10 for x in range(0, 12)]


df["col2"] = pd.cut(df.col1, bins=bins, include_lowest=True).astype(str)
```

Replace extra characters

```
df.col2 = df.col2.str.replace('(', '').str.replace(']', '').str.replace(' ', '').str.replace(',', '-')
```

result

```
    col1    col2
0   0.04    0-10
1   0.09    0-10
2   100.00  90-100
3   31.34   30-40
4   55.02   50-60
5   80.00   70-80
```

you can adjust the col2 ranges based on your requirement.

Comment: Using your code when I have 0.0 in col1 I have as an output nan in col2 ??? It should be 0-10 for values =0, could you fix it in your code?

Comment: srinath could you modify your code ?

Comment: sure. if you have 0, you can set the `include_lowest` parameter. Updated the answer

Comment: srinath using include_lowest = True and 0.0 in col1 I have -0.001 - 10.0 in col2, why there is -0.001 not 0.01 ? could you modify it please ? :)

Comment: it may be because your dataset contains `-0.001` and its the lowest of all. not sure what you are asking. can you please update the question with correct set of values.